# Is it possible to manipulate graphite data lies a couple of days in the past?

Tags: graphite

I have a graph in graphite, which I would like to manipulate. I noticed that datapoints of this graph that are already a couple of days in the past need to be corrected, because they are wrong. 
I tried to send the correct data with the older timestamps in order to overwrite the old data, but the data won't change. Does anyone have an idea?

Just to provide some more information:

```
xFilesFactor = 0.3
Aggregationmethod = average

Storage schema: 1m:1d,5m:30d,1h:3y
```

Comment: You are keeping 1 minute resolution for one day only.  After that, you are down to 5 minute resolution.  Since the data you want to change is more than a day ago, I'm not sure what you want is possible.  You could try sending the old data as five separate data points, one minute apart.  Hopefully Graphite will average them properly for you.

Comment: This does not seem to work. I have tried to send with higher resolution but Graphite does not pick up the data. I even tried to send data with a timestamp for every single second within the time frame.

Comment: I read somewhere that manipulating time older than the first interval (1d in your case) does not work or requires some whisper-magic-foo because you need to manually apply the aggregationMethod etc. Maybe [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/graphite/+question/170527).

Answer (score 0):

**Why it doesn't work for you-**

`Storage-Aggregation` config 'works on' new metric files. So any changes in this config will only affect newly-created metric files and not the ones that already exist.

`./whisper-info.py /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/stats/dev/hulk/getupdate.wsp` for example will tell you the effective storage and aggregation schema on ground zero.

**Editing these can be as straightforward as-**

`/whisper-resize.py {} --xFilesFactor=0.0 --aggregationMethod=sum 10s:1d 60s:30d 600s:365d <file_path>`

**I used the following scripts to change aggregation-schema of my already existing metrics-**

`$ find /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/stats/timers/production/ | grep .wsp > ~/timers`

`$ cat ~/timers | xargs -I{} sudo /opt/graphite/whisper-scripts/whisper-resize.py {} --xFilesFactor=0.0 --aggregationMethod=sum 10s:1d 60s:30d 600s:365d`

You can get these whisper scripts in the installation dump from [here](https://launchpad.net/graphite/0.9/0.9.10/+download/whisper-0.9.10.tar.gz).

The timestamp, perhaps has to be the same as the step.

Eg- If the retention is- XXX30 xxx50 xxx70 xxx90 and you send the new metric to xxx60, it will not be reflected.